# Object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.login-window').click(function () {
        //Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');
        //Fade in the Popup
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
        //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;
        $(loginBox).css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });
        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
        return false;
    });
    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I'm having a hard debugging the line $(document).ready(function() on my own PC this problem does not occur I'm using a different PC right now and I kept on having this error that the object does not support this property or method.

Comment: where is this error occuring? on the .ready() line itself? Is jquery actually loaded?

Comment: What's the HTML that goes with it? How about a jsFiddle?

Comment: `loginBox` is a string, as defined by the href it comes from. A string can't be a jQuery object as in `$(loginBox)`

Answer (score 3):

On line 5 you define loginBox as `$(this).attr('href')` then later try to use multiple jQuery functions on it. This is not possible because loginBox is not an element.

Comment: The href value is most likely a URL, so that's probably not what he wants, either.

Comment: true, but he might also be trying to target a div with a fragment url.

Comment: But a fragment URL should start with `#`, so your answer will create `##fragment`.

Comment: True... Would `loginbox.toString()` make it work? Nevermind, just realized `attr('href')` would return the whole url.